# Laravel eloquent retornando array do array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Tenho essa consulta utilizando eloquent

```
$data= \App\Logs::select('id', 'created_at') 
    ->get()         
    ->groupBy(function($val) {
        return Carbon::parse($val->created_at)->format('d-M-');
    })->toArray();
```

e ela retorna isso

```
array:2 [▼
  "06-Jul-" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "created_at" => "2017-07-06 13:21:15"
    ]
  ]
  "07-Jul-" => array:3 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "created_at" => "2017-07-07 13:43:23"
    ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 3
      "created_at" => "2017-07-07 14:18:36"
    ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
      "id" => 4
      "created_at" => "2017-07-07 14:18:41"
    ]
  ]
]
```

quando eu gostaria que ela retornasse

```
"06-Jul-" => "1"
"07-Jul-" => "3"
```

ou alguma coisa assim
nao estou entendendo oque estou fazendo de errado

Comment: Uma forma simples de dar a volta ao problema é contar a quantidade de elementos de cada data com o `count` do php. Tipo `count($x["06-Jul-"])`

Comment: É mysql?????...

Comment: Teria como editar a pergunta e colocar a estrutura da tabela Logs.

Comment: Você pediu a lista de ids no select, não a contagem (por dia). O query builder tem um [método `count`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#aggregates) pra isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agrupar os dos dados pelo dia e mês e contar, precisa trabalhar com [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset) método do [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) para agrupar e contar as linhas tudo isso em comandos [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) que trarão o resultado sem a layout esperado, depois utilize o método [transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-transform) para formatar a saída com o seguinte ***exemplo***:

```
$data= \App\Logs::select(\DB::raw('count(id),date(created_at)'))               
    ->groupBy('date(created_at)')
    ->get()
    ->transform(function($item, $key)
    {
      return [\Carbon\Carbon::parse($item['date(created_at)'])
          ->format('d-M-') => $item['count']];
    });
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-transform)
- [Ccollections - transform](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-transform)
- [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon)
- [Database: Query Builder - Ordering, Grouping, Limit, & Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Answer (score 1):

Guilherme, sei que sua pergunta foi específica sobre a consulta em *eloquent*. Mas sem a estrutura do banco fica difícil poder te ajudar. Uma solução paliativa seria usar `array_map` no resultado para formatar a saída da informação da consulta.

Algo assim:

```
$array = [
    '06-Jul-' => [

            [
                "id" => 1,
                "created_at" => "2017-07-06 13:21:15"
            ]
        ],
    '07-Jul-' => [
            [
                "id" => 2,
                "created_at" => "2017-07-07 13:43:23"
            ],
            [
                "id" => 3,
                "created_at" => "2017-07-07 14:18:36"
            ],
            [
                "id" => 4,
                "created_at" => "2017-07-07 14:18:41"
            ]
        ]
];

$array = array_map(function($item){
    return count($item);
}, $array);

var_dump($array);
```

**Resultado**

```
array(2) {
  ["06-Jul-"]=> int(1)
  ["07-Jul-"]=> int(3)
}
```